# Android 10: contentResolver.delete() is not deleting file from the file system

Tags: android, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I am using MediaStore.Files for creating my file in
InternalStorage/Documents/MyFolderName/xyz.pdf

using

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, fileType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, dstPublicDirectory + File.separator + dstSubDirectory);

        // Getting content uri for the file

        Uri dstFileUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues);
```

I am able to create that xyz.pdf file

but, in order to delete that file
I am using

```
 getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(fileUriToDelete, null, null);
```

the above is deleted from the database of MediaStore.Files but it is not able to delete that file in the filesystem.

As the file is still available in:
InternalStorage/Documents/MyFolderName
This is happening only in Android 10. In Android 11, that file is deleted from filesystem as well as MediaStore.Files db

Comment: Are you doing this work in a fragment?

Comment: yes, I am deleting that fileUri from a fragment

Comment: If you are on Android 10, you can use the File api.

Comment: For Android 10, you could use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and delete it through filesystem APIs.

Comment: I got one notice from Google play store to remove this flag. I removed it then. Just wondering will they allow my app to upload after this change?

Comment: @PerracoLabs the link is pointing to same question

Comment: @Surajkumar_cse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702967/android-10-how-to-delete-mediastore-item-and-its-associated-data-on-file-syste

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 10: How to delete MediaStore item and it's associated data on file system programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702967/android-10-how-to-delete-mediastore-item-and-its-associated-data-on-file-syste)

Answer (score 0):

[Kindly make Sure To Set Your Manifest Same as it , Same this issue i was facing My files was deleting on Android 11 but not deleting on Android 10 then I enable status of  and add this tag So And Specify Write Permission with

```
<android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"
 android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>`
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Also I attached picture link with title " 1" So click it and match your manifest

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31922223)