# Android Kotlin - Can not delete file from download folder

Tags: android, kotlin, delete-file

I am unable delete txt file from download directory. `File.delete()` does not work. I have also tried with `context.deleteFile()`, that does not work either. I am not getting any exception, just nothing happens. This works on many Android devices, but it does not work on the device that I needed it to work, which is Android device with embedded printer. Android version 8.1.

I have found this answer, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63554811/13404909), which is similar to official documentation [Google](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media_store).

I have tried to use `Uri.fromFile(directory)` and `directory.toUri()`
instead of `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` from the example, since file is in download folder, but I got null pointer exception.

How I can get correct download folder Uri? Or is there another way to delete file?

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

EDIT:

getAbsolutePath() = /storage/emulated/0/Download/print.txt

Code:

```
val downloadPath: File = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
// dowloadPath is passed as directory
fun readFile(directory: File, context: Context): String {
    val fileToRead = File(directory, "print.txt")
    //...
    if (fileToRead.exists()) {
        //...
        fileToRead.delete()
    }
}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

And inside **<application**

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:requestRawExternalStorageAccess="true"
```

Comment: You have to use content resolver

Comment: For an Android 8 device having the normal write permission in manifest and at runtime File.delete() should work. No need to mess around with uries and content resolvers.

Comment: Please tell value of file.getAbsolutePath(). And show your code.

Comment: Please do not post code to read that file. Only to delete it. One delete() only! Do not only tell the path but also post such code that we can check if you determined the path correct.

Comment: @blackapps, I have edited code section, and in readFile() is where file needs to be deleted.

Comment: Interesting, `fileToRead.canRead()` returns `true`, but `fileToRead.canWrite()` returns `false`...

Comment: Did you request write permission at runtime?

Comment: `android:requestRawExternalStorageAccess="true"` I never saw such. For what is it used?

Comment: @blackapps, that is the problem. I requested read, but not write. So stupid. For a RowAccess, I have found it in some answer and I just added it, and it stayed. It does not have impact on API<31. [requestRawExternalStorageAccess](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#requestRawExternalStorageAccess). Thank you for help.